# Libgdx: how to remove the border in the table

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I create the menu button in the table.
I did not point anywhere in the border the table but it is displayed.
I ran in the emulator or in desktop mode border appears
maybe I create the wrong table?

```
@Override
    public void show() {
        table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

//Button PLAY
        //скин кнопки плай
        btnplayStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
        btnplayStyle.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("play");//кнопка не нажата
        btnplayStyle.over = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("play");
        btnplayStyle.down = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("play"); // кнопка нажата
        playSkin = new ImageButton(btnplayStyle);
        playSkin.setSize(300, 200);

        stage.addActor(playSkin);
        playSkin.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
        });

        //Button score
        btnscoreStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
        btnscoreStyle.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("records");//кнопка не нажата
        btnscoreStyle.over = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("records");
        btnscoreStyle.down = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("records"); // кнопка нажата
        scorebutton = new ImageButton(btnscoreStyle);
        scorebutton.setSize(300, 200);

        stage.addActor(scorebutton);
        scorebutton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                game.setScreen(new Score(game) {

                });

            }
        });

        //Button EXIT
        btnexitStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
        btnexitStyle.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("exit");//кнопка не нажата
        btnexitStyle.over = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("exit");
        btnexitStyle.down = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("exit"); // кнопка нажата
        exxitbutton = new ImageButton(btnexitStyle);
        exxitbutton.setSize(300, 200);

        stage.addActor(exxitbutton);
        exxitbutton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });


        // table.add(heading);


        table.add(playSkin).width(400).height(100);
        table.getCell(playSkin).spaceBottom(30);
        table.row();


        table.add(scorebutton).width(400).height(100);

        table.getCell(scorebutton).spaceBottom(30);
        table.row();

        table.add(exxitbutton).width(400).height(100);
        table.getCell(exxitbutton).spaceBottom(30);
        table.row();
        table.debug();
        stage.addActor(table);
    }
```

[image: in the emulator or in desktop mode border appears]

After the start button will work properly, in the middle, but the border on each side as well created en understand because of what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at the very end of your code you have :

```
table.debug();
```

Which according to the LibGDX Scene2d.ui documentation
(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui)

> "enables debug lines for tables"

So, simply just remove that line of code and it should work!